# Export a large catalog with over 300,000 skus

Tags: catalog, csv, export

I am trying to export all products with Dataflow - Profiles/Export All Products and when I click on Run Profile in Popup the page loads and loads and finishes loading on a blank screen, and it doesn't create any file in /var/export. 
Seems to me like the server can't handle this much data.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Have you attempted to make smaller exports?  Ie, break it up into 1/6ths, 1/10ths, etc?

Comment: I am thinking about that. But how to break them?

Answer (score 1):

Increase your PHP timeout and memory limits.  In index.php, add the following lines:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","2048M"); // Try 4096M is this doesn't work
ini_set("max_execution_time", 14400);
```

To see exactly why it's erroring out on that blank screen, uncomment `ini_set("display_errors",1);` in index.php.